# Why my element always return the same value in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

Here is the code:

```
 for(var i = 0; i<aLotOfItems.length; i++){ 
    var tmpItem  =  aLotOfItems[i]; 

    //this will generate a <a> for me to handle the event
    tmpItem.toHTMLElement().prependTo($("#main"));

    //bind the click event
    $("#edit_"+tmpItem.m_sId).bind('click', function(){ 
        alert(tmpItem.m_sId);
    });                          
 }
```

First, I have a aLotOfItems array, then I take it one by one, to pass it in a tmpItem Object. and this object, have some htmlContent, I take it out, than, prepend to main, the toHTMLElement also will generate a  tag which use the edit_+m_sId to generate the id, then, I bind it to a click event. But finally, my result is all the click event is output the same result.... wt did I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to bind clicks one by one? Could'n you use some selector?

Comment: tmpItem is your own custom object and toHTMLElement is your own custom method?  If so, can you post that?

Comment: yes, I need set it one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of clousres/variable scoping, your `tmpItem.m_sId` var will get only its last value.  But if you do:

```
$("#edit_"+tmpItem.m_sId).bind('click', function(){ 
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

you will surely get different results.

**EDIT** Just in case you need to acces to your tmpItem inside your click event, you could use `.data` as this:

```
 for(var i = 0; i<aLotOfItems.length; i++){ 
    var tmpItem  =  aLotOfItems[i]; 

    //this will generate a <a> for me to handle the event
    tmpItem.toHTMLElement().prependTo($("#main"));

    //bind the click event
    $("#edit_"+tmpItem.m_sId).data("tmpItem", tmpItem).bind('click', function(){ 
        var tmpItem = $(this).data("tmpItem");
        alert(tmpItem.m_sId);
    });                          
 }
```

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: You are right, because the event is fired only after the `for` is completed.

Comment: one more question... If I have two elements, for example, the when the  $("#edit_"+tmpItem.m_sId) click, need to change somethings in $("#textarea_"+tmpItem.m_sId), but I can't using the "this" keywords, how can I do? Thank you.